# How to apply the css for thead in table sorter?

Tags: html, css

Previuosly there is no table sorter to my table grid .then my [image]table header color like the below.

After I added the table sorter to my table grid.then header colors are changed due to adding the thead statement. then i tried to give the tr class style to thead but no use.please tell me how to apply the old style to thead .

now my header color are like the below after adding the table sorter.
[image]

Code :

```
 <table class="ui"> 

    <thead>

    <tr class="ui-header">
    <th  id="DateSubmitted">Date Submitted</th>
    </tr> 

    </thead>

 <tbody> 

 <tr class="ui-content">
  <td><%: CreatedAt.ToShortDateString() %></td>
 </tr>

 </tbody>

 </table>
```

Please tell me how to apply the old color style to  thead.

Thanks

Comment: Post some code for us to help you out

Comment: Please check before there is no thead statement.now i added the thead statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Overwrite the style given by your table sorter library. Inspect the element of thead in firebug. try to disable styles given by your table sorter library.

Comment: by using inline statement am applying the style to thead but not effecting exactly.some default styles of thead correpting.I need to apply the default tr(ui-header) style to thead.check the above code.please tell me how to overwrite the thead style and need to assign the tr style to thead.